# VSCode: Open automatically integrated terminal and interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for python development. Every time i open a project, I have to run two commands:

```
Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal
Python: Show Python Interactive Window
```

Is it possible to have them run automatically at startup of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with this extension from the VS Market Place :

[Auto Run Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabrielgrinberg.auto-run-command)

> Run a vscode command on project init. Made to run wallaby.js automatically when a project is opened

Comment: Do you know if this works with project settings instead of user settings? The documentation refers to user settings.

Comment: The extension is configured from the user settings. But executes at the opening of a project.

Comment: These commands should be executed only for some projects but not for all. Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: You can add condition. By adding a specific file in your project, you can use the condition `hasFile`